# Defining a class as a particular object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capybara

I'm trying to create a class that is simply a representation of a particular object (in this case a capybara session).

```
class Capy
  require 'capybara'
  require 'capybara/poltergeist'
  def initialize
    Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
      Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app)
    end

    @session = Capybara::Session.new(:poltergeist)   
  end
end
```

Where I want my Capy Object to be a Capybara session with the appropriate settings. 
I think I might need to inherit the class
e.g.

```
class Capy < Capybara::Session
```

but I'm not sure how to do that before I've defined it or required capybara.

Comment: Move `require 'capybara'` outside of `class Capy`?

Comment: Sure, but if I do that, then how do I configure the Capybara session for this purpose?
Capybara::DriverNotFoundError: no driver called nil was found, available drivers: :rack_test, :selenium, :poltergeist

Comment: Why exactly are you trying to do this?  If your intention is to isolate the settings of one session from another its not really going to work since currently Capybaras driver registrations are global, and so are a lot of the session settings -  Creating multiple `Capy` objects is just going to end up changing the driver of other objects, etc.

Comment: I'm just trying to create something that I can call generally from various places in the application. i.e. we use capybara for automation for various things but I'm declaring it and creating the sessions in umpteen different places in the application. Perhaps it's not the greatest idea in teh world, but part of me says that surely I should be able to define the object to take on whichever properties I need. I'm just struggling to work out how to make a Capy object behave the same as a Capybara::Session one. In this case, a Capybara::Session created with a certain set of settings and variables.

Comment: @KeiranBetteley the problem is if you register a capybara driver in one object, and then register it again in another object with the same name, the first driver will be replaced by the second, you're trying to treat global objects as local and you'll end up with all sorts of unexpected behaviors

Comment: Thanks @tom. I'm really just trying to DRYly use capybara with the same setup in various parts of the application without having to declare it here there and everywhere. Maybe the approach is wrong, but I feel like my heart's in the right place...